# delete folders older than 12 hours in perl

Tags: perl

I need to delete folders older than 12 hours.

Here is my code, not complete of course. I don't know how to see the "age" of each folder in perl.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use v5.10.0;                                      
use File::Copy;
use POSIX 'strftime';
use File::Temp;



my $lapso  = 12;  #### is the limit of "age" in hours
my $hour = strftime("%H", localtime(time)); 
say "$hour";
my $limit = strftime "%Y%m%d$H", localtime( time - $lapso * 3_600 );
say "$limit"; #I get the limit of data 

my $dir    = '/home/sim/data/';
opendir(DIR,"$dir");
@files = readdir(DIR);
foreach $file (@files){
print $file, "\n";
}
closedir(DIR)
```

And not I need to compare the data of the folders with the $limit....

any help?

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html

Comment: Also: `strict` and `warnings` are strongly recommended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`stat`](http://p3rl.org/stat) to retrieve modification time of folder and compare it to current time to see if difference is more than 12 hours.

You might also be interested in [`File::Remove`](http://p3rl.org/File::Remove) module if the folders that you want to remove are non-empty.

Answer (score 4):

`-M` returns the age of a file/directory in days, so

```
print $dir, "\n" if 0.5 < -M $dir;
```

See the documentation: [-X](http://p3rl.org/-X)

Comment: `-M` returns how long it's been since the file has been modified. It doesn't return its age. This is impossible, since the OS doesn't keep track of when the file was created.

Comment: @ikegami Is there no portable perl version of something like `stat -f %c` because various OS versions can't  distinguish inode "birthtime" from "changetime" ?

Comment: @G. Cito,That doesn't even work on my GNU/linux. But yeah, the information is simply not there on some systems. I think creation date exists in the Windows world, but it's rare elsewhere.

Comment: I thought perhaps it was an optional and not always implemented part of POSIX but it appears to be file system specific [Fedora Ext4](http://serverfault.com/questions/351836/whats-birth-field-in-stat-command-output).  I'm pretty sure NTFS and ZFS support "birthtime" (and maybe even UFS with optional flags) but not all file system tools can read it.  Anyway off topic so I will cease to digress :-)

Answer (score -1):

You really want to use Perl? So, ok. :P

```
find . -type f -mmin +$((12*60)) -print0 | perl -n0e unlink
```